# Static Capturing Groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say we have the following regular expression:

```
((a(.+?)c ?)+)
```

This will match:

```
abc acc aac
```

What I want to do:

```
((a(.+?)c ?)(a\3c ?)*)
```

So that i will only match

```
abc abc abc
```

or

```
acc acc acc
```

but not item #2 (abc acc aac)

... But without the backreference.

Basically, I want the 3rd capturing group in #1 (.+?) to always match whatever the first match had.

Is this possible?

To make things hairier, this will need to work in JavaScript's regexp engine.

Comment: You want a regex **without** backreference? Because it seems backreference is what you need: `((a(.+?)c ?)(a(.+?)c ?)(a\3c ?)*)`

Comment: yes, js supports back-references and most other perl regexp features from which it is based...

Comment: @dandavis Just tested, I did not know this! I always thought that it didn't work in _JavaScript_. You've now opened up a whole new _RegExp_ world for me (not that I actually use it much over string operations)

Comment: I know it's possible in JS's engine to use backreferences, but that's exactly what I'm tying to avoid. It forces you to put redundant sub-expressions in your regex which would be nice to get rid of for readability's sake.

Comment: RegExp and readable should never be used in the same sentence...

Answer (score 0):

you can't capture the trailing space if it varies because the memorized value will be literally compared in later refs. moving the variation outside the capturing parens makes it simple:

```
var rx= /(a(.+?)c) ?\1 ?\1/g ;

// tests/demo
"abc abc abc".match(rx) // ["abc abc abc"]
"abc acc abc".match(rx) // null
"abc acc aac".match(rx) // null
"acc acc acc".match(rx) // ["acc acc acc"]
```

so, it's a few extra chars of repetition to allow optional spaces, but it works.

Comment: I was hoping to find something *without a backreference*

Comment: not sure i understand based on your examples. do you want to hard-code a different RegExp for "abc abc abc" than for "abc acc abc" ? you list a few combinations and to cover them all would take a lot of RegExp objects...

Comment: The second regexp does exactly what I want, but I want to know if it's possible to do so without a back reference. It should also match "adc adc adc" or "axc axc axc" -- but the middle character (whatever it is) needs to be the same in each repetition. I should also note that this is not the exact regexp I am trying to construct but rather a simplified version of it.